# PHP html and php rendering function

Tags: php, html, eval, render

I have a class called Tag which must render a PHP with HTML script dynamically.

```
public function render () {
  $render = '';

  $render .= '<' . $this->tagname;

  //attributes
  foreach ($this->attr as $attr) {
    if(isset($attr['name']) && isset($attr['value'])){
      $render .= ' ' . $attr['name'] . '="' . $attr['value'] . '"';
    }
  }
  if($this->tagtype == 1) $render .= ' />';
  if($this->tagtype == 2) $render .= ' >';
  if($this->tagtype == 0) {
    $render .= '>';
    foreach ($this->content as $content) {
      if(isset($content['type']) && isset($content['data'])){
    //content as HTML
    switch ($content['type']) {
      case 'html':
        $render .= $content['data'];
      break;
      case 'tag':
        $tag = $content['data'];
        $render .= $tag->render();
      break;
      case 'script':
        $render .= file_get_contents($content['data']);
      break;
      default:  break;
    }
      }
    }
    $render .= '</' . $this->tagname . '>';
  }

  return $render;
}
```

This function permit clean HTML insertion, other Tag instances and an external PHP file so I can use something similar.

```
$head->addTag(new Tag ('script',array('name' => 'src', 'data' => 'some_source')));
$body->addFile('nav.php');
```

Then, I just need to run `$site->render()` for it to be shown.

I was thinking about using `eval` but since it is normally unsafe I that there is any similar solution.

May you please tell me which direction would you use if you want to do such a thing?

Comment: Have you considered the use of DOMDocument DOM manipulation class for doing this sort of thing? Why re-invent the wheel?

Comment: @MikeBrant thank you for your reply, you're right I can use DOMDocument anyhow it will only work for HTML elements and I need also to import PHP scripts.